# Abelian extension and Dirichlet characters

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

$\newcommand\Q {\Bbb Q}
\newcommand\Z[1]{\Bbb Z/#1 \Bbb Z}
\newcommand\Gal{\mathrm{Gal}}
\newcommand\K[1]{\Bbb Q(\zeta_{#1})}$
Let $K/\Q$ be an abelian extension with Galois group $G$ and let $\rho : G \to \Bbb C^*$ be a character.

Let $\sigma_p \in \Gal(K/\Q)$ such that $\sigma_p(x)-x^p \in P$ for any $x \in \mathcal O_K$, where $P$ is any prime of $K$ above $p$.

> Is it true that there is an integer $k \geq 1$ and a Dirichlet character $\chi : (\Z k)^{\times} \to \Bbb C^*$ such that
>   $$\rho(\sigma_p)\Big\vert_{\Bbb C^{\,I_P}} = \chi(p)$$
>   for any rational prime $p$ ?

where
$\Bbb C^{\,I_P}$ is the $0$ or $1$-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb C$ invariant under the inertia group $I(P/p) \leq \Gal(K/\Bbb Q)$.

**Actually** I want to show that there is an integer $k \geq 1$ and a Dirichlet character $\chi : (\Z k)^{\times} \to \Bbb C^*$ such that
$L(\rho,s)=L(\chi,s)$ for any $s>1$, where the LHS is the Artin L function and the RHS is the Dirichlet L function.

---

**Ideas:**

— By Kronecker–Weber, there is an integer $k \geq 1$ such that $K \subset \K k$.
Let $\pi : \Gal(\K k / \Q) \to \Gal(K/\Q)$ be the projection and define  $\chi = \psi \circ \pi \circ \rho$, where $\psi$ is an isomorphism $(\Z k)^{\times} \to \Gal(\K k / \Q)$.

If $p$ is unramified, then $I(P/p) = 0$ for any $P$ above $p$, and we can take $\sigma_p$ to be the restriction of $\zeta_k \mapsto \zeta_k^p$ (where $(p,k)=1$). Then $\sigma_p$ is mapped to $p \pmod k$ via $\psi$, and $\chi(p) = \rho(\sigma_p)$ as desired.

But what happens for ramified primes? If $p$ is ramified, then $\chi(p) = 0$, so we would need $\Bbb C^{I_P}$ to be $0$. It doesn't seem to be true.

Comment: Notice that I defined : `\newcommand\Q {\Bbb Q}
\newcommand\Z[1]{\Bbb Z/#1 \Bbb Z}
\newcommand\Gal{\mathrm{Gal}}
\newcommand\K[1]{\Bbb Q(\zeta_{#1})}`

Comment: @user1952009 : thank you for your comments! However, I don't understand, since here my character $\chi$ is _fixed_ (or I have to find just _one_ Dirichlet character), while you are talking about several character**s**. If $p$ is ramified, then $\chi(p)=0$ for me, even if $\chi$ is primitive.

Comment: @user1952009 : Yes, but I'm not talking about the trivial representation. I'm talking about the Dirichlet character $\chi : (\Z k)^{\times} \to \Bbb C^*$, and again if $p$ is ramified then $p$ divides $k$ and $\chi(p)=0$.

Comment: See [there](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9783034802734-c2.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-1296041-p174249673) it makes a special case for ramification

Comment: @user1952009 : nice reference (Non-vanishing of L-Functions and Applications by Murty, M. Ram, Murty, V. Kumar) which I didn't know. Thanks! I'm not sure that it will completely answer my question, though.

Comment: Can you clarify what $\mathbb C^{I_p}$ is? What do you mean by the subspace - wouldn't it then always be $0$ or $\mathbb C$? For example, if $K=\mathbb Q(i)$, what would it be for $p=2$? Also is $\sigma_p$ meant to be a Frobenius element?

Comment: @Mathmo123 : 1. yes, this is a subspace of $\Bbb C$, either $0$ or $\Bbb C$ depending on $I_p$ acting trivially on $\Bbb C$ or not, via $\rho$. 2. This is indeed the Frobenius element **if** $p$ is unramified, but if $p$ is ramified this should be called "a" Frobenius element (only unique up to an element of $I_p$). Is it clearer now? :-)

Comment: And how does $I_p$ act on $\mathbb C$? A priori it only acts on $K$.

Comment: @Mathmo123 : as I said in my comment, $I_p$ acts on $\Bbb C$ via $\rho$, i.e. we look at $\rho(\sigma)(z)$ (for $z \in \Bbb C, \sigma \in I_p$). Here $\rho : G \to GL(V)$ is a one-dimensional representation with $V=\Bbb C$. I hope this is clearer now.

Comment: Ah OK. I haven't checked all the details so I won't post this as an answer. I think the problem is that $\rho$ naturally corresponds to a subextension of $K$, and not to $K$ itself. By Galois theory, the $\ker\rho$ is $\mathrm{Gal}(K/L)$ for some subextension $L$. $\rho$ now factors through a representation $\phi$ of $\mathrm{Gal}(L/\mathbb Q)$. The point is that now $L$ is unramified at $p$ if and only if $\phi(I_{L,p})$ acts trivially on $\mathbb C$, and your argument with Kronecker-Weber plus the various compatibilities of Frobenius elements and inertia should give the result.

Comment: @Mathmo123  : thank you very much for this useful comment. I will think about it. If you have some time to write up an answer in the next days, it would be a pleasure to read it. Anyway, I will think again about it.

Comment: @Mathmo123 : I think I managed to solve my problem thanks to your idea! If $p$ is ramified in $L$, then $\Bbb C^{I_{L,p}} = 0$ so that the restriction of $\rho(\sigma_p)$ is indeed $0$, and on the other hand $p$ divides $k$ since $p$ is ramified in $\Bbb Q(\zeta_k)$, so that $\chi(p)$ is also $0$, as wanted! The main trick is that we can assume WLOG that $\rho$ is injective (by considering $L$ and $\phi$ instead of $K$ and $\rho$ if necessary, by your construction). I will write it as an answer if I have some time.

Comment: Sounds good. Did you iron out the compatibility issue? For example, does everything work out at the primes which ramify in $L$ but not in $K$?

Comment: @Mathmo123 : I will check again, but for my purposes it should be fine: the Artin L-function satisfies $\mathcal L(C/A, \chi\circ \pi,s) = \mathcal L(B/A,\chi,s)$ where $A \subset B \subset C$ are Galois extensions of number fields and $\chi$ a character of $Gal(B/A)$, $\pi : Gal(C/A) \to Gal(B/A)$ the restriction to $B$. Apply this to $A=\Bbb Q,B=L,C=K$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand\Q {\Bbb Q}\newcommand\Gal{\operatorname{Gal}}$Thanks to [Mathmo123](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/154802/mathmo123)'s comments, I can provide an answer.

I will show that $L(\rho,s)=L(\chi,s)$, by showing that
$$\det(1-\rho(\sigma_P)p^{-s}, \mathbb{C}^{I_P}) =  1-\chi(p)p^{-s}$$ for any prime $p$.

Without loss of generality, we can assume that $\rho$ is faithful. Let $H = \mathrm{ker}(\rho)$, and $\pi_H : G \to G/H$ the projection, where $G=\Gal(K/\Q)$. Then, from theory about Artin L functions, we have
$$\mathcal L(K/\Q, \rho,s)=\mathcal L(K^H/\Q, \phi,s)$$
where $\rho = \phi \circ \pi_H$ (and $K^H/\Q$ is abelian).
So we can replace $\rho$ and $K$ by $\phi$ and $K^H$ if necessary.

— If $p$ is not ramified in $K$, then $\sigma_p$ corresponds to $p$ as I said above. We get
$$\det(1-\rho(\sigma_P)p^{-s}, \mathbb{C}^{I_P}) =  1-\chi(p)p^{-s}.$$

— If $p$ is ramified, then $I(P/p) \neq \{id\}$ and since $\rho$ is injective, we have $\rho(I(P/p)) \neq \{1\}$. Therefore $\mathbb{C}^{I(P/p)} = 0$ and $\det(1-\rho(\sigma_P)p^{-s}, \mathbb{C}^{I_P})=1$.
But $p$ is also ramified in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_k) \supset K$, so $p$ divides $k$, so that $\chi(p)=0$. We also have $1-\chi(p)p^{-s}=1$ i.e. we also get
$$\det(1-\rho(\sigma_P)p^{-s}, \mathbb{C}^{I_P}) =  1=1-\chi(p)p^{-s}$$

which concludes the proof.

Comment: Hi, your argument is not correct because $$\zeta_{\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_k)}(s) =\prod_{\chi \bmod k} L(s,\tilde{\chi}) \tag{1}$$ where $\tilde{\chi}$ is the primitive character underlying $\chi$. For $p$ ramified, that $\det(I-p^{-s}\rho(\sigma_p)|V^{\rho|_{I_p)}})= 1$ or $1-tr(\rho(\sigma_{\mathfrak{p}})) p^{-s}$ depends on that $\rho|_{I_p}$ is trivial or not. A solution could be to find $p,e(p),f(p),g(p),\sigma_p,I_p$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_k)$ in order to show $(1)$ is true, then to deduce what we get for $e,f,g,I_p$ in subfields and their representations.

Comment: A representation $\rho : \text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q}) \to GL_n$ is unramified at $p$ iff $\rho|_{I_p}$ is the trivial representation. In that case the local factor at $p$ is of degree $n$.

Comment: @reuns : I don't understand _where exactly_ my above argument fails. I was able to show proposition 5.12 in Neukirch's Algebraic Number Theory book (which takes into account the ramified primes).

Comment: (Notice also the difference between $\rho\vert_{I_P}$ and $\rho(\sigma_p)\vert_{V^{I_P}}$).

Comment: I told you, if $p$ is unramified in $K$ then $\rho$ is unramified at $p$, but if $p$ is ramified in $K$ it doesn't mean $\rho$ is ramified at $p$. Here $\det(I-p^{-s}\rho(\sigma_p)|V^{\rho|_{I_p)}})=1$  iff $\rho(g) \ne 1$ for some $g \in I_P$.  $V^{\rho|_{I_P}}$ is the subspace of $\mathbb{C}^n$ onto which $\rho|_{I_P}$ acts trivially. Another example : for $\rho$ the trivial representation $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q}) \to GL_1$ then $L(s,\rho) =\zeta_\mathbb{Q}(s)$ ie. $\rho$ is unramified at every prime.

Comment: In your question you should modify : **actually** I want to show $L(s,\rho) = L(s,\tilde{\chi})$ for some **primitive** Dirichlet character $\tilde{\chi}$. If you don't care of primitivity then you can even forget the ramified primes and $L(s,\rho)_{unramified} = \prod_{p\ \nmid\ k}  \det(1-\rho(\sigma_p)p^{-s})^{-1} = \prod_{p\ \nmid\ k} (1-\chi(p)p^{-s})^{-s} = L(s,\tilde{\chi} 1_{(n,k)=1})$

Comment: Is it clear now ?

Comment: @reuns: my character $\chi := \rho \circ \pi \circ \psi$ is primitive if the integer $k$ is taken to be _minimal_ (which I didn't require above, I agree).