# Galois groups and groups of Dirichlet characters

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, characters, galois-extensions

Assume we have Galois extension $K/\mathbb Q.$ Let be $(G,\circ)=\text{Gal}(K/\mathbb Q)$ its Galois group and let be $(X,+)$ group of Dirichlet characters, that "belongs to this field extension". Now, what is relation between $X$ and $G$?

Comment: Could you make it more precise how Dirichlet characters are associated to $K/\Bbb{Q}$? For **abelian** extensions see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2075219/abelian-extension-and-dirichlet-characters).

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more precise and specific. Let's start with a character $\chi\text{ mod }n:\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)/\mathbb{Q})\to\mathbb{C}^\times$, where I equate $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)/\mathbb{Q})=(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$. Now can I somehow (in a different way) describe fixed field $F$ of $\ker \chi$?